# uploading image file error

Tags: php, html, file-upload, xampp

this php script is retuning errors when I try and upload a file.  I'm using XAMPP on a  win xp machine.  I believe I've set sharing permissions correctly.

the script:

```
//For images
if (isset($_FILES['image300x100']) && !empty($_FILES['image300x100']['tmp_name'])) {

    $name = $_FILES['image300x100']['name']; // getting the name of the file
    $tempName = $_FILES['image300x100']['tmp_name']; // getting the temporary file name.
    $allowedExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' );// specifying the allowed extentions
    $a = explode('.', $name);
    $fileExt = strtolower(end($a)); unset($a);//
    $fileSize = $_FILES['image300x100']['size'];

    $filePath = "";
    switch($category){
        case 1 : $filePath = "c:/www/Perspect/categories/politics/articleImages"; break;
        //etc etc etc
    }

    $path = $filePath;

} else{
    $errors[] = 'no file selected';
}

$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tempName, $filePath);
```

left as it is the error is:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a     directory in C:\www\Dev\admin\addNewArticle.php on line 62
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Server\XAMPP\tmp\php62C.tmp' to 'c:/www/Dev/categories/bla/articleImages' in C:\www\Dev\admin\addNewArticle.php on line 62
```

I removed the `c:/`from the path which I thought was the correct path but that gave a result of:

```
temp nameC:\Server\XAMPP\tmp\php62E.tmp filepath     
www/Dev/categories/bla/articleImages
Warning: move_uploaded_file(www/Dev/categories/bla/articleImages): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\www\Dev\admin\addNewArticle.php on line 62

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Server\XAMPP\tmp\php62E.tmp' to 'www/Dev/categories/bla/articleImages' in C:\www\Dev\admin\addNewArticle.php on line 62
```

Any help hugely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the destination file name, e.g.:

```
$filePath = "c:/www/Perspect/categories/politics/articleImages/file.png";
```

Alternatively you could generate a random name.

Comment: I'll be giving it a name that's specific to the image size but can I appen the filename to the move function instead of in the path?

Comment: i think I realise what I was doing wrong, I was regurgitting some earlier code, that code used a fucntion which appended the filename. derp[

Comment: @SteveGreen Yeah you can append it in the `move` function instead. Is it working now?

Comment: I just changed :  $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tempName, $filePath."testFile.png");

it's working except the file is showing as 0 bytes.

Comment: @SteveGreen You're missing a `/` - i.e. `move_uploaded_file($tempName, $filePath . "/testFile.png");`

Comment: lol, just noticed too! :)  the file on the server was in a different location because of that.

Comment: @SteveGreen Just to let you know as well, you can use a relative path. E.g. `$filePath = '../images';` or similar.

Comment: I would normally use relative but I had a ton of issues before so for this site, eveything has an absolute path.  Not as nice but it saves any mistakes.  Which I make a lot of :)

Comment: thanks for your help and comments, working fine.  Just need to append the names etc but that should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the second argument is a directory, not a file. You need to add the filename to the destination path.